# Customize Android TabWidget from XML

Tags: android, tabwidget

I have been looking around on how to customize Android TabWidget using XML with no luck. All examples that I have found is showing how to customize TabWidget using Java code. Is it possible to customize [i.e change the background color, change the text color, etc] TabWidget using XML alone? If so, can you redirect me to a document on how to do it or possibly a code snippet?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your own styles, state- and layer drawables, and apply them to your `TabWidget` in the layout xml.

A working example can be found at [this answer's update part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799320/android-remove-space-between-tabs-in-tabwidget/5804436#5804436), I hope it will help you work it out.