# Adding image to custom tab

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-custom-view

I use [this](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136) example for creating custom tab. I don't know how to add image in tab view.

I try adding `ImageView` element in tabs_bg.xml but image is not displayed, only text

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgTab"
    android:background="@drawable/img"/>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the `android:src` attribute for the `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgTab"
    android:src="@drawable/img"/>
```

With no content (src), its size will be 0x0 (due to `wrap_content`).

Specifying the indicator (header) of a tab view is made from java code, usually chained:

```
myTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(myTab).setContent(intent);
```

where `myTabHost` is your `TabHost` instance, and `myTab` is a `View` instance that will be used as the header of this tab.

You can create your own tab: define its layout in xml and add all the views (image, text...) you need on it.

For reference (complete sample) see the [update part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799320/android-remove-space-between-tabs-in-tabwidget/5804436#5804436).
The `layout/tab.xml` file contains the layout of the tab headers (including an icon too).