# i want to remove the default spacings between tabs in android how can i do that

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android remove space between tabs in tabwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799320/android-remove-space-between-tabs-in-tabwidget)

I want to remove the default spacings between tabwidget in Android. How can I do that?

Following is my xml:

```
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:background="#000000"
        /> 

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
        /> 
  </RelativeLayout>
```