# How can I remove the space between tab widget?

Tags: android

I would like to know how to remove space between tab widgets,Am new to android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android remove space between tabs in tabwidget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799320/android-remove-space-between-tabs-in-tabwidget)

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799320/android-remove-space-between-tabs-in-tabwidget) question. He basically says create your own drawables without padding. Did you google this at all? I searched for "android remove space between tab widget" and the first link brought that question up.