# Android TabHost Divider not working in 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-tabhost

This is the code I am using to set the divider between by tabs in the tab host.

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tabdivider);
```

But it does not show up in the emulator. Searching around on SO led me to many posts regarding  this but I have not been able to come to a perfect solution to this.

Any help/suggestion in this regard will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TabHost is **deprecated** in android api level 11 onwards.

Try using [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

For more details, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297293/andorid-how-can-i-replace-the-deprecated-tabhost).

**UPDATE**:

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523083/tab-dividers-not-showing-in-ics), for using `setDrawable` in `ICS`.

**UPDATE:** 
If you want to make use of tabs on all android versions, you can use the following code:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {

// setup action bar for tabs
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(R.string.artist)
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<ArtistFragment>(
                    this, "artist", ArtistFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
        .setText(R.string.album)
        .setTabListener(new TabListener<AlbumFragment>(
                this, "album", AlbumFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
} else {

// put your TabHost code here...

}
```

This should be placed in your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Is there no way to achieve this using TabHost ?

Comment: TabHost works perfectly on android 4, but it is suggested that, you should use ActionBar, and seriously they are very easy to use. I can explain you that. And if you want to use only TabHost then, you have provided not enough info about the problem. Exactly what problems are you facing?

Comment: The problem is that the divider does not show in the device even though I have used setDividerDrawable() as given in the question.

Comment: I have updated the ActionBar link. If you want, please go through it.

Comment: I will still suggest you to use ActionBar. Because, using TabBar in ICS, is not good practice. If you have any specific requirement then its ok.

Comment: Where you see TabHost is deprecated? http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html

Comment: Actually TabActivity is deprecated, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html