# Actionbar tab selection divider color

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar

In the picture below from [the developers guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style) of android you see the light blue edge underneath the tabs. I tried to style this small edge with an other color but i had no success.

Meanwhile i succeed to style the action bar, and tabs. But the only thing i can't get succeed on is changing that little blue edge. I even don't know how its called in the guide.
Because the divider is the little stripe between all the taps:

[   BALLOONS  |  BIKES   | ANDROIDS  |  PASTRIES  ]

Can someone help me with this?
Which style i have to use to change this color?

The follow line didn't work out:

```
<item name="android:actionBarDivider">@drawable/divider</item>
```

[image]

Comment: May be this answer helps? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9173927/459413

Comment: I see what he did there, i will try it as soon as i get home! thank you vasart.

Comment: you can get the answer from there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172504/how-to-style-the-divider-between-ice-cream-sandwich-tabs

Answer (score 2):

Use pagerslidingtabstrip library for making tabs if youy want to use actionbar tabs then here is the code

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/customTabBar</item>
```

code for devider in action bar tab indicator

```
<style name="customTabBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabBar">
<item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
<!-- give your divider here -->
<item name="android:divider">@drawable/tabindicator</item>
<item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>
```

where @drawble/tabindicator is a picture in drawble

Answer (score 0):

It's called Tab HairLine Style.
You can use this tool to generate and probably figure out how to change the color : http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: Incorrect.  Tab Hairline style controls the underline height.