# Customize FragmentTabHost set TabWidget on bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml

currently I'm trying to implement the FragmentTabHost for my project. I'm still new on this fragments but I found it very great in terms of reusing the layouts, etc which is why I wanted to push myself further on to it. Now I read the tutorials on how to create a Tabs with fragment and I came on this tutorial:

http://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/

Now this works just fine, except that the tabWidget is on top of my layout where I wanted it to be on bottom. I find that I need to setup the tabWidget after all the tabs has been initialized so I tried to add these codes:

```
mTabWidget = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);

    mTabWidget.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mTabWidget.setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE);
    mTabWidget.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Now this one already eliminated the divider and changes the color but obviously won't put my Widget on the bottom part of my layout. Now how would I do that?

I also tried to edit the Tabhost xml and just put the TabWidget after the FrameLayout but nothing happens. here's the xml:

```
    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have refer this link [github example](https://github.com/rameshkec85/BottomTabsFragmentTabHost)

**This will be your layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

**For your custom Tabs :**

```
mTabHost.addTab(setIndicator(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1"),
                        R.drawable.image1),

    public TabSpec setIndicator(Context ctx,TabSpec spec, int resid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.tabs_text, null);
        v.setBackgroundResource(resid);
        TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
        text.setText(spec.getTag());
        return spec.setIndicator(v);
    }
```

**Edit**

```
 //To set drawable to your perticular TAB 
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_login);
```

**end Edit**

**If you want to add drawable (selector):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_compose_h" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_compose_h" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_compose"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: Currently checking it out. :)

Comment: Hi Gru, tested it and yeah it works! But I have one problem. The tabDividers shows and I don't know to set it off. as well as I cant change the color of the tabs. How should I do that?

Comment: @KaHeL check this answer on stack for [remove tabDividers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172504/how-to-style-the-divider-between-ice-cream-sandwich-tabs) and for second doubt you have to update your **selector** according what color you want.

Comment: Yeah, I already got the concept of the solution from the link you've given and already applied it. Once again thanks! :)